# Editing using Javascript

Tags: javascript, url, youtube-api

I was trying to put a youtube video into an iframe, when I realized that you have to put "embed" between youtube.com and the video id. The only problem is that I am extracting these urls from an API so all my urls are in one array and are the direct url to the video.

Is there any way for me to edit this url so that I can add embed in between?

Comment: sorry guys I didn't mean parsing. I meant editing.

Comment: Could you show an example of the URL you have and what you'd like?

Comment: My url would come in thefeeds[0].link and I would want it to have an embed in between. http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string.replace

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGSy3_Czz8k";

var embedurl = url.replace("watch?v=","embed/");
```

So if you wanted to replace everything in your array

```
for (var i = 0; i < thefeeds.length; i++) {
    thefeeds[i].link = thefeeds[i].link.replace("watch?v=","embed/");    
}
```